# Creating central config file with hundreds of defined names

Tags: php

I want to create a central config file, with a few hundred of defined setup configure names, that would be included with something like:

```
include config_file_name.php
```

I want to write the php code in the config file as follows:

```
<?php
function config($name) {
foreach name_text_line,
read each line,
change text line to be the $defined_name,
like:

$text_line_name = other_function ( 'setting_data_name' );

/* the first name section changes as shown below, 
but the = other_function is always the same and the 
'setting_data_name' is also the same code */
} 

text_line_name1
text_line_name2
text_line_name3
text_line_name4
text_line_name5
text_line_name6
text_line_name7
text_line_name8
text_line_name9
and_many_more99
?>
```

So when the above function is included with include file.php, I want function to all respond as if its the same as the following code:

```
<?php
$text_line_name1 = other_function ( 'setting_data_name' );
$text_line_name2 = other_function ( 'setting_data_name' );
$text_line_name3 = other_function ( 'setting_data_name' );
$text_line_name4 = other_function ( 'setting_data_name' );
$text_line_name5 = other_function ( 'setting_data_name' );
$text_line_name6 = other_function ( 'setting_data_name' );
$text_line_name7 = other_function ( 'setting_data_name' );
$text_line_name8 = other_function ( 'setting_data_name' );
$text_line_name9 = other_function ( 'setting_data_name' );
$and_many_more99 = other_function ( 'setting_data_name' );
?>
```

I don't want the include file to have a lot of extra characters or code, just pretty simple with a little code if needed above or below on other lines, so I can add one name line of a new configuration as needed. Its not a list of peoples names, sorry if that confused anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable name or the:
`$variable`
Can all be the same name.

As long as the array name or the:
`$variable['array_name']`
Is different words, then there is no need to make a long list of variables in a config file.

*Note, make sure that you don't have similar keys in your config file*

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to create hundreds of individual PHP variables, when you could have a single array?  There are also libraries that can read yaml, ini or json format?

- For Yaml files, you either need a parsing component library or to use
  the yaml pecl extension.
- ini file support is built into php
- json is built in

A yaml example:

```
names:
  - bob
  - fred
  - john
  - mark
  - joe
```

.ini example

```
names[] = bob
names[] = fred
names[] = john
names[] = mark
names[] = joe
```

.json example

```
[
    "bob",
    "fred",
    "john",
    "mark",
    "joe"
]
```

or

```
{
    "names": [
        "bob",
        "fred",
        "john",
        "mark",
        "joe"
    ]
}
```

If this is a file you intend to update frequently, or that will be updated programmatically, it's not a great idea to have some PHP code, and then intermix some other data that you intend to read in order to create variables.  This is why DOTENV, yaml, json and ini files are used heavily for configuration, across a variety of programming languages and utilities.

XML is also frequently used, and in all cases there are libraries and or built in PHP functions available to read them.

Last but not least, there are various file reading options with php.  The simplest is [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php).

```
<?php
$names = file('/path/to/names.txt');
// $names is array with one entry per line.
```

Comment: Your idea is not solving the main problem. I want the text lines to be plain text without other additional characters like quotes or equals and such. I also do not want to use any third party frameworks/libraries. I want to do it completely through built in php functions.

Comment: @AngelHess I explained that every one of the options I provided are built-ins.  You might help people see the forest through the trees, if your question was better illustrated to show not just what you are asking for but what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I added a final option for you, just using file() to read a file off the filesystem. There are a number of other file reading functions you could use alternatively.

Comment: Ok I changed the words a bit but I don't understand what you mean by forest. I thought my words are simple and pretty clear because I wrote examples of exactly what I am wanting to do. That is the problem. Sorry.

Comment: I don't know what you changed, but the problem remains the same.  You describe a desire to want to create a bunch of `variables`.  Why?  You say they are configuration variables but your example has `no values` so this configures what exactly?  All my prior comments remain the same.  I provided numerous ways that people read in configuration files to work with their application.  If they don't work for you, you need to describe better why that is.

Comment: The problem is you are thinking like a programmer and I am thinking like a visual artist person. The values are another part, and not related to my question at all. I don't understand why you ask about the values. The part where I write setting_data_name is a section in a database but that is not related to my question, I don't think. :-/

Comment: I'm the only person who has engaged with you on your question.  That should tell you something about the clarity and approach of your question.